# Script saying "Exception: The coordinates of the target range are outside the dimensions of the sheet" and not working after months of being used

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

Here's the script I have that was working and has been working for months until now.  It is linked to a sheet that is filled out with a form.

```
    function onedit(e){ 

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var activeRange = e.source.getActiveRange();  
  var sortRange = sheet.getRange(2,1,sheet.getLastRow(),sheet.getLastColumn());
  
  if(sheet.getName() == "Shopping List" && (activeRange.getColumn() == 6 || activeRange.getColumn() == 11) && activeRange.getValue() !== "SpartanNash"){
    sortRange.sort([{column: 11, Decending: true },{column: 6, Decending: false }]);
  }
  else if(sheet.getName() == "SpartanNash" && activeRange.getColumn() == 11){
    sortRange.sort({column: 11, Decending: false });
  }
  else if(sheet.getName() == "Shopping List" && activeRange.getColumn() == 6 && activeRange.getValue() === "SpartanNash") {
    var activeRow = activeRange.getRow();
    var spartanNashSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("SpartanNash");
    var spartanNashRange = spartanNashSheet.getRange(spartanNashSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    sheet.getRange(activeRow, 1, 1, 11).copyTo(spartanNashRange);
    sheet.deleteRow(activeRow);
  }
}
function switchList(e){ 
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var activeRange = e.range;
  var sheet = activeRange.getSheet(); 
  var store = e.values[5];
  
  if(sheet.getName() == "Shopping List" && store == "SpartanNash") {
    var activeRow = activeRange.getRow();
    var spartanNashSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("SpartanNash");
    var spartanNashRange = spartanNashSheet.getRange(spartanNashSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    sheet.getRange(activeRow, 1, 1, 11).copyTo(spartanNashRange);
    sheet.deleteRow(activeRow);
  }
}
```

On the email I get with the failure notice it says "    Exception: The coordinates of the target range are outside the dimensions of the sheet"

Please help me figure out why it's not working and what I need to change.

Comment: I can't be sure but it appears you have 2 installed triggers.  onedit(e) and switchList(e).  Which one is failing?

Comment: Please add the textual error message (including the file name and the line number)

Comment: Both are not working.  When I run them in debug mode both show (e) as undefined

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property "source" from undefined. (line 3, file "Code")Dismiss

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property "range" from undefined. (line 23, file "Code")Dismiss